# Can you get a Chinese tourist visa without an arrival date?

Tags: china, tourist-visas

Sometimes I find some cheap flight tickets from Stockholm to Beijing and Shanghai. I know a Swede must have a visa for touristing in China but I don't know when I'd like to go as these cheap tickets aren't availabe all the time (a very special price code).

Can you get a Chinese visa without an arrival date?

The site visaforchina.org says I should submit arrival and departure dates as *Supporting Documents* - something I can't do as I can only say "within the next 6 months, less than 30 days stay".

Comment: Why not wait to get the visa until you buy the ticket?

Comment: @ajd could be a same-day ticket.

Answer (score 1):

No you can not, as you have read, the tourist VISA requires arrival and departure dates to be written on the application, and if requested tickets needs to be provided so you cannot just make them up, what you can do is apply for a business VISA, this works different in that a company would write an invitation letter stating that you would be needed in China for the period of Jan 1 to June 1 for example multiple times for meetings, that way you do not have to provide the actual dates when applying for the VISA, the are multiple companies who can help with this.

[ButlerBobs is one of them](http://www.butlerbobs.com)

DISCLAIMER: I am the Founder of ButlerBobs

Comment: Wouldn't that be a fraud?

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder no as long as we do a consultation and take on the responsibility of the person we vouch for it is not, it requires a special license which we have

Comment: I see. Could you provide a typical price range for these kinds of services?

Comment: There is no extra charge as long as you are a member of the service, the same is for us, AnyHelper and others